# Active Directory UserPrincipal issue

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have some code which gets a user based on the current context and this happens in the `Page_Load()` method of my application.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc", "DC=domain,DC=com", "user", "password");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
string Name = user.Name.Trim();
lblName.Text = Name;
```

This works and the label is correctly showing the logged in user (Windows Authentication).

However, another part of my code, on button press, does some looping through a datagrid which contains other usernames and uses a similar method to obtain information about those users.

I've utilized labels on the page to display relevant user information but one of those labels seems to change based on which user it is dealing with in the loop, when it actually needs to only ever refer to the currently logged in user.

Is there a way around this? I thought by having separate methods that essentially do the same thing, I would get different objects. The return values are different so I'm not sure how this is happening.

Relevant code below with some comments to explain or point out where the code is not relevant (sending emails and dealing with exceptions - all removed).

```
public string getUserEmail()
{
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc", "DC=domain,DC=com", "user", "password"); ;
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
string email = user.EmailAddress;
return email;
}

public string getOtherUserEmail(string user)
{
user = user.Trim();
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc", "DC=domain,DC=com", "user", "password");
UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, user);
string email2= u.EmailAddress;
return email2;
}

protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gdView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label FullName = gdView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lblFullName") as Label; // other username from gridview
            string FromAddress = getUserEmail(); //logged in user
            try
            {
                string otherName = FullName.Text.ToString(); 
                string ToAddress1 = getOtherUserEmail(FullName); //Other user
                //Generate an email message....
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
                lblMessage.Text = "Email sent!";
            }
            catch
            { // exception handling
            }
    }
}

protected void gdView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            TableCell cell = gdView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2]; //Cell containing "other" user name
            Message.Text = cell.Text;
            string otherName = cell.Text.ToString();
            string ToAddress = getOtherUserEmail(otherName); //Other user
            string FromAddress = getUserEmail(); //logged in user
            try
            { //email as above
            }
            catch
            { // exception handling
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you posted, I would expect you to get different objects as well.  Maybe there's something happening in code you haven't included?

On a side note, for the current logged on user you should define a field (call it `_loggedOnUser`) outside of the `Page_Load()`.  That way all methods have access to it.  This will keep your code easier to follow, also, and might even solve your reference problem.

```
public partial class Page1 {

    UserPrincipal _loggedOnUser;

    public void Page_Load() {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc", "DC=domain,DC=com", "user", "password");
        _loggedOnUser= UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        string Name = _loggedOnUser.Name.Trim();
        lblName.Text = Name;
    }

}
```

Then you can refer to it in the rest of your class, and you won't have to waste time going back to Active Directory in your loop.

Thus, this line: `string FromAddress = getUserEmail();`

can be changed to `string FromAddress = _loggedOnUser.EmailAddress;`

and you avoid another expensive call to AD to get info you already have.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense although I get a warning by using the new variable: `Field 'Project._default._loggedOnUser' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`. I tried initializing it with a null value but it didn't like that either.

Comment: Did you change the code in `Page_Load()` to initialize it?  If so, try setting a breakpoint to see if it gets hit.

Comment: I forgot that bit. Have figured out that the (poor) exception handling code is causing my error label to contain the other user's name. Literally no idea how this is happening, so I will try to debug! Thanks for your help though, i will mark it as the answer.